# How to create a view model object that gets information from multiple database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following tables:-
[image]

But how I can create a view model class inside my asp.net mvc4 web application, so that if I pass the AccountDefinition.OrgID I can retrieve the following:-

•   accountDefinition

•   SDOrganization

•   SDOrgPostalAddr

•   AaaPostalAddress

I have created the following CustomerDetails ViewModel

```
public class CustomerDetails
    {
        public AccountDefinition AccountDefinition {get; set;}
        public SDOrganization SDOrganization {get; set;}

        public virtual ICollection<AaaPostalAddress> AaaPostalAddress { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection< SDOrgPostalAddr> AaaPostalAddress { get;set; }

    }
```

I have the following Repository method, which should populate the CustomerDetails based on the ORG_ID:-

```
public   CustomerDetails GetCustomer(int ORG_id) {

CustomerDetails cd = new CustomerDetails();
var cd = from SDorg in cd.AccountDefinition // here I will b populating the CustomerDetials
        }
```

My second question , as I have a database experience, I would do a stored procedure that join the the tables together then return the result back !!!, but as I am using the entity framework so I got confused on how to do so?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created an entity framework model from your database schema you should have:

- An `AccountDefinition` class with an `AccountDefinition.SDOrganization` reference navigation property because the relationship between the two is apparently one-to-one
- A `SDOrganization.AaaPostAddresses` collection navigation property because the relationship is many-to-many. The `SDOrgPostalAddr` table should not appear as model entity because it is only the many-to-many link table

With this model and changing your view model to...

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    public AccountDefinition AccountDefinition {get; set;}
    public SDOrganization SDOrganization {get; set;}

    public ICollection<AaaPostalAddress> AaaPostalAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

...you should be able to get the result using:

```
var customerDetails = context.AccountDefinitions
    .Where(a => a.OrgID == givenOrgID)
    .Select(a => new CustomerDetails
    {
        AccountDefinition = a,
        SDOrganization = a.SDOrganization,
        AaaPostalAddresses = a.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

You can also fetch the same data by *eager loading* the `AccountDefinition` entity together with the needed navigation properties:

```
var accountDefinition = context.AccountDefinitions
    .Include(a => a.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.OrgID == givenOrgID);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. will your fist approach load the data as lazy loading ? If yes then is there a way to force it to load the data as eager loading?

Comment: @johnG: No, it's not lazy loading. It will be a single DB query like eager loading with `Include`.